# Getting multiple NETWORK_PROVIDER from LocationManager

Tags: android, networking, provider, locationmanager

How does LocationManager choose which NETWORK_PROVIDER to use when getting location data? I would like to be able to identify the providers that LocationManager selects the NETWORK_PROVIDER from.

For example, there are two nearby NETWORK_PROVIDER locations, X (close) and Y (not as close).  When standing in a single spot, sometimes the NETWORK_PROVIDER will be X, sometimes Y. I assume that the location with the highest accuracy gets returned (which is why usually X is returned), and all other networks are ignored, but I would like to return a list of all the nearby networks (or at least the top 2 or 3) at the same time.

Any of the .getProvider() methods (as far as I know) return the type of the provider (network, gps, passive), but nothing to actually identify the provider. When the location is returned, the location data is unique for the providers, but cannot be used to choose providers.  I can get data from X, but I can't tell the program to ignore X (or can I?).

Anyway to make this happen? To return a list or array of NETWORK_PROVIDERS and then step through them getting location data?

And no, using GPS_PROVIDER is not an acceptable answer, because I need NETWORK_PROVIDER data only.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not based on any evidence, but rather my understanding of how the location provider works. When you request NETWORK_PROVIDER, you're basically asking it to give you the location that they estimate based on all the information that is available. For example, you might have 3 wifi networks and 2 cell towers, and that info is sent up to a server on the internet. Using that info, they calculate where they think you are, and return that to you. So, in other words, the network_provider location is based on the sum of all wifi/cell-tower info available to your phone.

Individually, a wifi hotspot doesn't tell you too much about where you are. A cell tower gives you some location info, but you'll need a few sources to accurately triangulate your location. Also, note that you need a internet/data connection, since the location is determined by some server, and not done on your phone. This is because knowing the nearby wifi hotspots (more specifically the MAC addresses) is useless without a database that maps each hotspot to it's physical location.